# How to give separate access to AWS device farm?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My scenario is like this. I have created two projects aws in the device farm. Let's assume project x project y. I have two IAM users named john and Kevin. Jhon's project is x, Kevin's project is y. I need to give separate access to Jhon and Kevin to access their device farm project. Furthermore Jhon can not see project y while Kevin can not see project x in device farm.
To do that I add aws given JSON policy but it says "***This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition.*** "
I add below aws JSON policy to do that. Please help me.thank you

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"GetTestGridProject",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "devicefarm:GetTestGridProject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:testgrid-project:123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655441111"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"ViewProjectInfo",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "devicefarm:ListTestGridSessions",
            "devicefarm:ListTestGridSessionActions",
            "devicefarm:ListTestGridSessionArtifacts"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:testgrid-*:123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655441111/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post so the policy is readable by using code block?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to do this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ViewProjectInfo",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "devicefarm:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:testgrid-project:123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655441111",
                "arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:testgrid-session:123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655441111/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This will limit access to the content of projects / sessions using the ID `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655441111`.

You can obviously scope the access down to the API level if need be, but this will get you started.

See also: [AWS Documentation on IAM Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_controlling.html)

Comment: I add your JSON policy with correct IDs but when I add the policy again it says "This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition. For details, choose Show remaining Learn more"

Comment: This is just a warning message that says that the policy is technically not valid for all the APIs included on the list. If you want to create the policy without the warning, use the Visual Policy Editor filter out the AWS Device Farm APIs to only the `*TestGrid*` ones, then enter the required **resources** / **condition** entries that will show up as orange warnings on the policy editor.

Comment: Thank you @Tobe.